# Are questions related to funding of open source AI research and development relevant here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic

Are questions related to **funding** of open-source AI research and development relevant here?

(I am working as a research engineer at [CEA LIST](https://www-list.cea.fr/) in France, and developing at home, with others, the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) symbolic AI system)

My employer would let me work on [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) symbolic AI system from the office if I get funded (e.g. by some future [ITEA](https://itea3.org/) project) on it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this type of question should be made on-topic here, but it may also depend on the question (maybe you can provide a few examples of questions that you have in mind?).

The reasons are

1. the site should focus on the theoretical, philosophical, and social aspects of artificial intelligence, but questions asking about funding your project do not seem to fall into any of these categories (maybe apart from the social category), as this problem is not strictly related to AI
2. answers to these questions could get outdated very quickly, given that the funding opportunities may expire after a while, so these questions could potentially only be useful to the person that asked them, but, ideally, [questions should also be relevant for other future visitors](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

I'm not sure which other Stack Exchange website could be suitable for this type of question. Maybe you could ask this question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/?